# How to compare timestamp with date without time in JPQL?

Tags: jpa, jboss, jpql

I'd like to get objects with `create_date = :my_date` where `create_date` is in `2014-12-02 14:49:15.029` format and `my_date` is in `2014-12-02` format in JPA.

Is there any way to compare timestamp column with Date object (yyyy-MM-dd format) in JPQL using `NamedQuery` or should I use native query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using jpql try to use

```
date(timestamp_column)
```

eg :

```
@Query(select te from Testentity te where date(te.createdTimestamp) >= CURRENT_DATE)
 public List<Testentity> getTestDate()
```

Comment: Thank you save my day :)

Comment: Always Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NamedQuery, you need to properly manipulate the @[Temporal](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html) annotation and the [TemporalType](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html) enum.

So if your object property is a Date without a time portion, you would annotate it as `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)`, further on when supplying a parameter to your named query you would use one of the two available signatures

```
setParameter(String name, java.util.Date value, TemporalType temporalType)
setParameter(String name, java.util.Calendar value, TemporalType temporalType)
```

so your query will have a part like:

```
query.setParameter("my_date", myDate, TemporalType.DATE)
```

Comment: But what if I don't want add this annotation? I use time from this property but only in this one query time doesn't matter for me. I tried to setParameter with TemporalType.DATE but generated SQL didn't cast timestamp column to date.

Comment: For what concerns the casting, is the underlying SQL type TIMESTAMP or DATE, or to rephrase, make sure that in your DB the column is of type TIMESTAMP

Comment: I'm sure the column is timestamp. It takes me too much time, I will use native query istead. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I have tested id and your method helps but unfortunately I don't want to use this @Temporal annotation.

Comment: this is not working when @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) is used on the column definition in entity. Dont you have sollution for this case?